# Office 365 Connector for Stack Overflow

Tags: app

#### About:

Office 365 Connectors are a great way to get useful information and content into your Office 365 Groups or Microsoft Teams. Using the StackOverflow connector, users can get notified about questions for specific tags that they want to follow.

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet:

[image]

#### Download / Install:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms.exch.eac.connectorselection(v=exchg.150).aspx

#### Platform:

Office 365

#### Contact:

o365connectorsupport@microsoft.com